# How to load numpy array to gensim Keyedvector format?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, gensim, embedding

After I trained word embeddings, I saved it as npz format.
While I am trying to load it as KeyedVectors format, it makes errors.
How can I load numpy array as gensim.KeyedVectors format?
I really need it because I need to use functions like most_similar() not just vector values.

in model.py with tensorflow,

```
self.verb_embeddings = tf.Variable(np.load(cfg.pretrained_target)["embeddings"],
                                               name="verb_embeddings",
                                               dtype=tf.float32,
                                               trainable=cfg.tune_emb)
```

in saving.py

```
target_emb = sess.run(model.verb_embeddings)
np.savez_compressed("trained_target_emb.npz", embeddings=target_emb)
```

in main.py

```
 model = KeyedVectors.load('trained_target_emb.npz')
```

I got

```
_pickle.UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered, but no persistent_load function was specified.
```

also tried

```
 model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('trained_target_emb.npz')
```

but got

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xde in position 14: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gensim `KeyedVectors` instances can't be loaded from a mere raw array: there's no information about which words are represented, and which indexes hold which words.

The plain `.load()` in gensim expects objects that were saved from gensim, using gensim's own `.save()` method.

Word vectors can be loaded from files that are in the same format as was used by the original Google/Mikolov `word2vec.c` tool. So perhaps your tensorflow code can save them that way?

Then, you'd use `.load_word2vec_format()`.